# how to set the highlight value stored?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have object in Unity and when I hover it highlights that particular object, but what I want to do is when I hover and it highlights - I want to select and store that highlight value to show stable and still on that object? Is there a way with my code below? Thanks for the help.

Here is my highlight code:

```
public class Highlights : MonoBehaviour {

        public Material highlightMaterial;
        Material originalMaterial;
        GameObject lastHighlightedObject;

        void HighlightObject(GameObject gameObject)
        {
            if (lastHighlightedObject != gameObject)
            {
                ClearHighlighted();
                originalMaterial = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial;
                gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = highlightMaterial;
                lastHighlightedObject = gameObject;
            } 
        }

        void ClearHighlighted()
        {
            if (lastHighlightedObject != null)
            {
                lastHighlightedObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = originalMaterial;
                lastHighlightedObject = null;
            }
        }

        // Navigates to highlight every object on camera. 
        void HighlightObjectInCenterOfCam()
        {
            float rayDistance = 1000.0f;

            // The ray from the center of the viewport.
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));
            RaycastHit rayHit;

            // Check if we hit something.
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayHit, rayDistance))
            {
                // Get the object that was hit.
                GameObject hitObject = rayHit.collider.gameObject;
                HighlightObject(hitObject);
            } else
            {
                ClearHighlighted();
            }
        }

        void Update()
        {
            HighlightObjectInCenterOfCam();
        }
    }
```

My method for trying to capture the highlight value when selecting:

```
        public void Editcomponents()
        {    
            ClearText();
            CircleImageStatus = !CircleImageStatus;
            var imgs = reticle.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>(true);
            if (CircleImageStatus)
            { 
                foreach (var img in imgs)
                {
                    img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(235, 210, 52, 255);      
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var img in imgs)
                {
                    img.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);               
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: comment out the `ClearHighlighted();`  call in `HighlightObjectInCenterOfCam`?

Comment: I would have a look at the `else` branch in `HighlightObjectInCenterOfCam`. That seems to be responsible for "unhighlighting" when the mouse is not hovering an object any more. You would have to call `ClearHighlighted` when hitting a new object, though.

Comment: @germi it already calls `ClearHighlighted();` in `HighlightObject` if it's a new object

Comment: @Ruzihm ah, true. I missed that.

Comment: Do you already have a method that's called when you want to "set" the selection? Is that what `Editcomponents` is? Do you have a method that's called when you want to "unset" the selection?

Comment: yes, but it does not set the highlighted value when I hover over the object. it does show the highlighted value but it does not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean to track if the selection is set or not that starts out `false`, and gets reset back to `false` whenever the highlighted object is undefined or destroyed.

Only do any highlighting related stuff (i.e., removing or adding highlights) when the boolean is `false`:

```
public class Highlights : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material highlightMaterial;
    Material originalMaterial;
    GameObject lastHighlightedObject;

    bool highlightSet; // new

    void Start() // new
    {
        highlightSet = false;
    }

    void HighlightObject(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        if (lastHighlightedObject != gameObject)
        {
            ClearHighlighted();
            originalMaterial = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial;
            gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = highlightMaterial;
            lastHighlightedObject = gameObject;
        } 
    }

    void ClearHighlighted()
    {
        if (lastHighlightedObject != null)
        {
            lastHighlightedObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = originalMaterial;
            lastHighlightedObject = null;
        }
    }

    // Navigates to highlight every object on camera. 
    void HighlightObjectInCenterOfCam()
    {
        float rayDistance = 1000.0f;

        // The ray from the center of the viewport.
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));
        RaycastHit rayHit;

        // Check if we hit something.
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayHit, rayDistance))
        {
            // Get the object that was hit.
            GameObject hitObject = rayHit.collider.gameObject;
            HighlightObject(hitObject);
        } else
        {
            ClearHighlighted();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // unset highlight if object is null (undefined or destroyed)
        if (lastHighlightedObject == null)
        {
            highlightSet = false;
        }

        if (!highlightSet)
        {
            HighlightObjectInCenterOfCam();
        }
    }

    public void SetHighlight() 
    { 
        // only set highlight if there is a highlighted object
        if (lastHighlightedObject != null) 
            highlightSet = true; 
    }

    public void UnsetHighlight() { highlightSet = false; }

    public void SetHighlightToObject(GameObject to) {
        if (to != null) {
            HighlightObject(to);
            highlightSet = true;
        } else {
            ClearHighlighted();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, you would call `SetHighlight` when the highlight is to be set, and `UnsetHighlight` when it is to be unset.

If you want to set the highlight to a specific gameobject, you can call `SetHighlightToObject` with a reference to the gameobject you want to set. You could get this with `GameObject.Find("objectname");`  where `"objectname"` is something stored in a database, for instance.

Comment: one last question can you store the highlighted value to firebase database? is it possible?

Comment: @GaryJackson I've never used firebase, sorry!

Comment: @GaryJackson I added a bit more to the answer about how to move towards that. If you need more info, I would ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), include the code you're using, and link back to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611292/1092820) because this answer is already getting a little broad.